# Using live data, how to display a dialog only once?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I want to display an alert with a message using live data. The problem I have is whenever the activity is resumed the alert pops up again. Any hints?

Comment: this answer and its link is very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178259/3643361

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a custom live event that is triggered only once. This discussion has already took place on [Android's Architecture Google Samples Repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63). Here's a [proposed solution](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) I like.

In case you need it in kotlin, there it goes:

```
class SingleLiveEvent<T>: MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
        }

        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, Observer<T> { t ->
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(@Nullable t: T?) {
        pending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    /**
     * Used for cases where T is Void, to make calls cleaner.
     */
    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "SingleLiveEvent"
    }
}
```

Using this it won't trigger you dialogs twice unless you call `yourLiveData.value = newValue` again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Set a `boolean isShown = false;`

When you show the dialog set it to true and save it to Shared preferences. show the dialog only isShown is false.