# MVP vs MVVM: how to manage alert dialogs in MVVM and improve testability

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-mvp

I'm MVP lover but at the same time I'm open minded and I'm trying to improve my knowledge about MVVM and databinding:

I have forked here https://github.com/jpgpuyo/MVPvsMVVM

the original repo https://github.com/florina-muntenescu/MVPvsMVVM
from @FMuntenescu

I have created several branches. In one of them, I want to show 2 different alert dialogs with diferent styles depending of the number of clicks performed on a button:

- even number of clicks -> show standard dialog
- odd number of clicks -> show droidcon dialog

You can find the branch here:
https://github.com/jpgpuyo/MVPvsMVVM/tree/multiple_dialogs_databinding_different_style

I have created 2 observable fields in view model and I have added one binding adapter.

Activity:

```java
private void setupViews() {
    buttonGreeting = findViewById(R.id.buttonGreeting);
    buttonGreeting.setOnClickListener(v -> mViewModel.onGreetingClicked());
}
```

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:greetingType="@{viewModel.greetingType}"
    app:greetingMessage="@{viewModel.greetingMessage}">
```

ViewModel:

```java
public ObservableField<String> greetingMessage = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<GreetingType> greetingType = new ObservableField<>();

public void onGreetingClicked() {
    numberOfClicks++;
    if (numberOfClicks % 2 == 0) {
        mSubscription.add(mDataModel.getStandardGreeting()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(greeting -> {
                    greetingMessage.set(greeting);
                    greetingType.set(GreetingType.STANDARD);
                }));
    } else {
        mSubscription.add(mDataModel.getDroidconGreeting()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(greeting -> {
                    greetingMessage.set(greeting);
                    greetingType.set(GreetingType.DROIDCON);
                }));
    }
}
```

MVVMBindingAdapter:

```java
@BindingAdapter({"greetingType", "greetingMessage"})
public static void showAlertDialog(View view, GreetingType greetingType, 
String greetingMessage) {
    if (GreetingType.STANDARD.equals(greetingType)){
        new DialogHelper().showStandardGreetingDialog(view.getContext(), 
        greetingMessage, greetingMessage);
    } else if(GreetingType.DROIDCON.equals(greetingType)) {
        new DialogHelper().showDroidconGreetingDialog(view.getContext(), 
        greetingMessage, greetingMessage);
    }
}
```

With MVVM, not sure about how to implement it to be fully testable with java unit tests. I have created a binding adapter, but then:

- I need a if/else in binding adapter to show one dialog or another.
- I don't know how to inject a dialog helper into binding adapter, so I can't verify with unit tests, except with powermock.

I have added different styles for each dialog, because if I don't put styles, we can consider that title and message from dialog are retrieved from data layer, but it would be strange to consider that a android style is from data layer.

Is it ok inject a dialog helper into MVVM to solve this problem and make code testable?

Which would be the best way to manage alert dialogs with MVVM?

Comment: After a bit research, I found the [SingleLiveEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146081/show-dialog-from-viewmodel-in-android-mvvm-architecture) approach.
And I also found a [interesting discussion](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63) where Hannes Dorfmann is proposing  a model view intent approach. With this approach, I could create 2 different states: one for each dialog.
Anyway, it would be another approach, and from my point of view, MVP is still offering more testability than MVVM or MVI because presenter knows the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I use for MVVM is mixed, as follows.

From the article from Jose Alcérreca mentioned in the Medium post [LiveData with SnackBar, Navigation and other events (the SingleLiveEvent case)](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) referred in the SO answer to [Show Dialog from ViewModel in Android MVVM Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146081/show-dialog-from-viewmodel-in-android-mvvm-architecture), I choose the forth option "Recommended: Use an Event wrapper". The reason being that I'm able to peek the message if needed. Also, I added the `observeEvent()` extension method from [this comment in Jose's Gist](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9#gistcomment-2748514).

My final code is:

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

/**
 * Used as a wrapper for data that is exposed via a LiveData that represents an event.
 * See:
 *  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150
 *  https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9
 */
open class LiveDataEvent<out T>(private val content: T) {

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}

inline fun <T> LiveData<LiveDataEvent<T>>.observeEvent(owner: LifecycleOwner, crossinline onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) {
    observe(owner, Observer { it?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let(onEventUnhandledContent) })
}
```

Usage is like so (my example triggers the event when data synchronization finishes):

```kotlin
class ExampleViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _synchronizationResult = MutableLiveData<LiveDataEvent<SyncUseCase.Result>>()
    val synchronizationResult: LiveData<LiveDataEvent<SyncUseCase.Result>> = _synchronizationResult

    fun synchronize() {
        // do stuff...
        // ... when done we get "result"
        _synchronizationResult.value = LiveDataEvent(result)
    }
}
```

And consuming it by using `observeEvent()` to have nice, concise code:

```kotlin
exampleViewModel.synchronizationResult.observeEvent(this) { result ->
    // We will be delivered "result" only once per change
}
```