# Android MVVM dialog viewmodel

Tags: android, mvvm, dialog, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I'm developing an app with MVVM pattern and architecture components viewmodel with hilt di.
Now I want to use viewmodel in dialog but dialog doesn't have `by viewModels()` delegation to initialize viewmodel. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Dialog from ViewModel in Android MVVM Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146081/show-dialog-from-viewmodel-in-android-mvvm-architecture)

Comment: @AbanoubAsaad No, my problem isn't show dialog, I have to use viewmodel in dialog

Answer (score 2):

`by viewModels()` is a `Fragment` **extension function**.
If you need a *ViewModel* probably you also need to use a `FragmentDialog` instead of your current implementation for better separation.

With `FragmentDialog` `by viewModel` should work, since `FragmentDialog` extends `Fragment`

Comment: So what is proper way of using dialog (not fragmentDialog) in mvvm?

Comment: If it's a simple dialog then `MaterialDialog` is a good option I think -> https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#dialogs

If it has logic (needing a viewmodel indicates it has some more complex logic), than use a `FragmentDialog` with a `ViewModel`. Which basically is a `Fragment`, but it's shown as a dialog